# Assinging a scope variable to data in http service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-material

```
app.controller('contentixaeng', function ($scope, $http)  {

    $scope.subject = function(){
        $scope.code=101;
    };

  $http({
    method: "POST",
    data:{
        'subj_code':$scope.code, 'action':'singledata'
    },
    url: "pages/Entries/connectixa.php"
  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
  }, function myError(response) {
    $scope.error = response.data;
  });
});
```

I am trying to pass the value of $scope.code to data in HTTP service. It's not working properly and no data value is shown as output. Instead, I get the error "ng-repeat dupes".

The function subject get called through this line

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-contoller="contentixaeng"><a class="nav-link" href="#" ui-sref="ixaeng" ng-click="subject()" >English</a></li>
```

If I change the code like shown below then it works

```
app.controller('contentixaeng', function ($scope, $http)  {

    $scope.subject = function(){
        $scope.code=101;
    };

  $http({
    method: "POST",
    data:{
        'subj_code':101, 'action':'singledata'
    },
    url: "pages/Entries/connectixa.php"
  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
  }, function myError(response) {
    $scope.error = response.data;
  });
});
```

I want different data to be passed to the database search based on the on-click event.

Answer (score 2):

The http request is sent immediatly when the controller is created. At this point `$scope.code` is not yet set.

Try something like this:

```
app.controller('contentixaeng', function ($scope, $http)  {

  $scope.subject = function(){
      $scope.code=101;
      callBackend();
  };

  function callBackend() {
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      data:{
        'subj_code':$scope.code, 'action':'singledata'
      },
      url: "pages/Entries/connectixa.php"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.error = response.data;
    });
  });
}
```

Like this the http request is sent only when the `callBackend` method is explicitly called.

Answer (score 1):

If you're receiving `ng-repeat dupes` error that means that you've got duplicated entries in `$scope.users`- try debugging that and see what's going on there. Also, you can use `track by` option like below:

```
ng-repeat="user in users track by $index"
```

It will assure that each `user` will be treated as unique entity, even if you have duplicated entries in `$users` variable.

Another thing is, where this piece of code is run? I do not see it anywhere in the code you provided

```
$scope.subject = function(){
    $scope.code=101;
};
```

Comment: I have added the code which calls the function. Please check the question above now